# Echoing my usrs payout is not working

Tags: php, mysql

So on my website, I am trying to show my user his amount of money that he has made using this code `<?php echo $row['payout']; ?>` but when I do that, no information shows up.

But when I echo the user's username like `<?php echo $row['username']; ?>` it shows him his username. I think the issue is that they are both in different tables. I just do not know how to fix it. My tables are named `as_users` and `as_user_details`.

Comment: not enough code ...  update your question and show you code with query and use of the result  ..

Comment: Please share the query you are using to fetch the data from database. Also show info on how the tables are named and how your current php code looks like.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Add your code to the question. This sounds similar to yesterday's question.

Comment: what kind of code to the question? and it is pretty similar

Comment: The `select` query.

Comment: add the code youre currently using

Comment: If possible share your table structure, and first check before echoing that your variable $row['payout'] is !empty($row['payout']). If you are fetching  these records from two different tables then first check that you have a join or not.